# Read image from xml

Tags: xml, model-view-controller

i have a XML file with url of images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <images>

<image id="1" small="http://media.tui.nl/59A/59AF4B8BB168D7EE3864873DC94CD41A.jpg" medium="http://media.tui.nl/A44/A44212A7F5A3A9DD0C83639B8EC6112F.jpg" large="http://media.tui.nl/567/5676F657D4BF7919392B171A3211FB76.jpg" original="http://media.tui.nl/B03/B030D8D22F741C34B50CD268B317E33C.jpg"></image>

<image id="2" small="http://media.tui.nl/CF0/CF075719EC75F15190A7BFAA8945F55D.jpg" medium="http://media.tui.nl/97F/97F6543A1DCD75F2DD73FBDCCC08B729.jpg" large="http://media.tui.nl/4DC/4DC8F79590A0B11ABFE8783C7C57AAB5.jpg" original="http://media.tui.nl/3D9/3D908C66FA1C223C2D69BEE6EBCA6CC0.jpg"></image>
```

And i need show the images in my page, but i dont know how read of XML to load images.:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhotoCarousel";
}

<h2>PhotoCarousel</h2>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="align-items:center">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">            
            <img src="readFromXML">  
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="readFromXML">           
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="readFromXML">           
        </div>

    </div>
```

Instead of

```
<img src="readFromXML">
```

that I have to put?

Comment: You need to parse the xml for the links and put those links in your img src.

Comment: thanks, but i cant modify XML file

Comment: k, but you don't need to modify it...

Comment: then? ... I do not understand

Comment: write a function to read the image href values from your xml.  then use said values and put them where you want them in our markup.